# I reverted back to MVC4, but now I can't build to a build server

Tags: tfs

I am using VS 2012 and TFS 2010.
Recently I failed to upgrade my application from MVC4 to MVC5.
In order to do that I had to reassign the projects in my application to .Net Framework 4.5.
The application worked on my development machine, but I could not get it to build to the build server.
So in TFS version control I reverted back to the MVC4 version using .Net Framework 4.0.

Now I find when I try to build to the build server, it fails.
The error messages show that it is trying to build code that I had written for the MVC5 version.
Yet that code no longer exists in my application.
So I do not know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you provide the error message(s) you are receiving?

Comment: Actually I found that the way I reverted back was to overwrite the application to a specific source control version. The problem was that for the build it gets the latest version from source control, putting the code back to where it was. So I need to find a way to make sure that the version I hold locally becomes the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a Rollback.  Make sure you have the latest version locally, do a View History, select the changesets you want to get rid of, right-click and Rollback.  Then check-in the Rollback changes.